# Dynamic img creation through a link without attaching multiple instances

Tags: javascript

I have a link that is attached with an "onclick" function. When pressed it attaches an img element into a separate div called "mediaBox". The problem I'm having is that if it's pressed multiple times then it attaches more instances of the img. How can I control this. I'm still new to JavaScript and I prefer to receive this answer in pure Javascript not jQuery, as I will cross that bridge after I have a full understanding of Javascript.

```
var rkf = document.getElementById("submenulinks").getElementsByTagName("li")[0];

rkf.onclick = function(){
    var client = document.getElementById('client');
    var description2 = document.getElementById('description2');
    var role = document.getElementById('role');
    var mediaBox = document.getElementById('mediaBox'); 
    var thumb = document.getElementById("thumb");       
    var client2 = document.getElementById("client2");
    var newImage = document.createElement("img");

    client2.innerHTML = "Role - Applications";
    client.innerHTML = "RKF Real Estate";
    client2.innerHTML = "Role - Applications";
    description2.innerHTML = "Quarterly Catalog of Exclusive Listings managed by RKF";
    role.innerHTML = "Custom designed Cover and listings content. Tables were also utilized within Indesign. <br><br><b><i> Photoshop and Indesign</i></b>";

    newImage.setAttribute("src", "../images/rkf_cover.jpg");
    newImage.setAttribute("height", "500px");
    newImage.setAttribute("width", "387px");
    newImage.setAttribute("alt", "rkf");
    newImage.setAttribute("href", "#");
    mediaBox.style.backgroundImage = "none";
    document.getElementById("mediaBox").appendChild(newImage);
    newImage.style.display = "block";
    newImage.style.marginLeft = "auto";
    newImage.style.marginRight = "auto";
    newImage.style.marginTop = "25px";  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rkf.onclick = function(){
    var client = document.getElementById('client');
    ...
    ...
    ...

    // Remove the handler after it ran once.
    this.onclick = null; // <<<<<========================
}
```

Since you do want to use jQuery in the future, it's equal to:

```
$('#submenulinks li:first').one('click', handler);
```

Comment: hi gdoron and thanks for replying, I actually did try that but then I had a new issue in that if another link in my UL was pressed the mediaBox div would be passed a new image which is the effect, but It would make my original link unusable if a visitor clicked on it again. I'm not sure if I explained that clear enough?

Comment: You can also find the actual file here: http://www.jasonsanchez.3owl.com/sandbox/sbbranding.html